# App Engine development server fails to detect logged-in user

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, service

I'm trying to use App Engine's UserService on a local development server and it's not behaving as I expect. I searched the forum for answers to my question but couldn't find any that specifically address my problem.

The first thing I do is get a login URL from the UserService as follows:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
if(userService.isUserLoggedIn())
  String loginURL = userService.createLoginURL("/mycallbackservlet");
else
  ... do something else
```

Assuming the user is not logged in initially, I provide a 'mycallbackservlet' as destination URL to be redirected to after (successful) login. To start the login procedure I open a GWT window on the client side as follows:

```
Window.open(loginURL, "Bla", props);
```

The loginURL is the one created above. I'm presented with the local development server's simulated login screen where you can type in any user. I just click OK. Now my callback servlet is called (as expected) but when I retrieve the UserService object again it does not give me a logged in user, that is

```
UserServiceFactory.getUserService().isUserLoggedIn()
```

returns 'false'. How can this be? Is this typical development server behavior or am I doing something wrong? Should I have opened the initial URL differently, that is, not using Window.open() but something else?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are createing login url when user is already logged in? Shouldn't it be  vice-versa:

```
if(!userService.isUserLoggedIn())
  String loginURL = userService.createLoginURL("/mycallbackservlet");
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpServletRequest has method has methods

- getRemoteUser()
- getUserPrincipal()
- isUserInRole(String role)

That could be useful in your situation.